# Uncaught ReferenceError: down_value is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function

Estoy tratando de hacer a base de dos botones un incremento y decremento de la variable que se mostrará en mitad de estos, la variable la uso en la función que llamo desde la de cada botón. Como puedo solucionar este error?
Mi html es el siguiente:

```
       <script src="incrementos.js"></script>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>
                      <button class="incremento" onclick="down_value()">
                          Disminuir
                      </button>
                  </td>
                  <td class="middle" id="i_tempobj">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                      <button class="incremento" onclick="up_value()">
                          Aumentar
                      </button>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          </div>
```

Mi javascript es este:

```
//Creo una función para aumentar el número
function up_value(){
  i_NTemp = i_TempObj + x;
  temperatura_objetivo();
  document.getElementById("i_tempobj").innerHTML=i_NTemp;
  console.log(i_NTemp);
}
//Creo una finción para disminui el número
function down_value(){
  i_NTemp = i_TempObj - x;
  temperatura_objetivo();
  document.getElementById("i_tempobj").innerHTML=i_NTemp;
  console.log(i_NTemp);
}
```

Comment: Pues va a ser que incrementos.js no contiene ese código javascript que pones o está en otra ruta. Revisa la consola a ver si ves un 404. A mi [me funciona](https://jsfiddle.net/cgeny2pj/) (me da otros errores pero ya son dentro de la función que sí encuentra). También podria ser que te diera un error de javascript antes de llegar a definir esas funciones y petara todo el script.

Comment: En las funciones usas las variables `i_TempObj` y `x` que no están definidas en ningún lado, al menos en el código que has mostrado

Comment: @vfg están definidas mas arriba perdón por no ponerlo

Comment: Edita la pregunta entonces para que nos enteremos. Pero entonces... ya me imagino qué es lo que pasa. Lo defines fuera de la función, así que cuando las defines el `<td id="i_tempobj">` todavía no existe. Será mejor que las definas en cada función

Comment: @masterguru en el código hago clic en donde llamo a incrementos.js y me lleva bien al archivo

Comment: Revisa la consola con F12 mientras recargas la página a ver si ves errores de algun tipo antes de pulsar los botones.

Comment: relaxedrt, acostúmbrate a poner todo el código relevante, por favor. Además de `i_TempObj` y `x` también haces referencia a `temperatura_Objetivo()` que si no es relevante para tu error, podrías obviarlo.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que te propongo funcionaría correctamente...

```
const x = 1;
function up_value(){
    var i_TempObj = parseInt(document.getElementById("i_tempobj").innerHTML) || 0;
    i_NTemp = i_TempObj + x;
    // temperatura_objetivo();
    document.getElementById("i_tempobj").innerHTML=i_NTemp;
    console.log(i_NTemp);
}
//Creo una finción para disminui el número
function down_value(){
    var i_TempObj = parseInt(document.getElementById("i_tempobj").innerHTML) || 0;
    i_NTemp = i_TempObj - x;
    //temperatura_objetivo();
    document.getElementById("i_tempobj").innerHTML=i_NTemp;
    console.log(i_NTemp);
}
```

Eso sí... como ves, `i_TempObj` está definido dentro de cada función. También podrías definirlo fuera si lo haces cuando la página está completamente cargada (con `window.onload`)